# How do I rename a project in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, rename

i have a finished application written with objective c and I would like to rename the file. how do i do that?

Answer (score 5):

Recent versions of Xcode have a "Rename..." item in the Project menu.

Comment: Nice, hadn't seen that one either. Renaming a project used to be a pain.

Comment: No kidding. I can't remember exactly when the menu option was added, but it was pretty recently.

Answer (score 2):

Renaming a project has changed in Xcode 4+. (Kris Markel's answer above is for Xcode 3.2.x )

> Follow these steps to rename your application in Xcode 4.0 or later:
>
> 1. In Xcode, select your target under "Targets" in the project editor, then choose View > Utilities > Show File Inspector.
> 2. Xcode opens the file inspector pane. Enter your application's new name in the Project Name field as shown in Figure 1, then hit the return key on your keyboard.
> 3. Xcode displays a project-rename dialog that contains all the items that can be renamed in your project. Leave your application selected in the dialog and deselect all other items as shown in Figure 2, then click Rename to perform the rename operation.
>
> [image: Figure 1]
> [image: Figure 2]

Source: [iOS Developer Library Technical Q&A QA1625](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1625/_index.html)