# How to rename xcode project file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I rename a project in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868427/how-do-i-rename-a-project-in-xcode)

Hi I am tying to change the name of the file that my xcode project is sitting in. however as soon as I try to do this when I load the project back up all of the file names inside the navigator menu turn red...

updated question, I was able to rename my project but it did not change this
[image]

its still showing testtable2... I have no idea why.. Is it because of the folder name this whole project is sitting in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First, BACKUP YOUR PROJECT**

In 4.1:

*Slowly* double click on the **text** of the project name (right to the blue xcode icon). Type in the new project name and Rename the Project content items in the dialog.

Or in older versions of Xcode (not sure the exact version):

Click `Menu > Project > Rename...`, and select your new name.

The preference file contains lots of hard coded references to the project name, so you can't just rename the file through Finder/Terminal.  The old way was a lot of painful grepping, etc.

Comment: I think its different for 4.2 now. because I cannot find menu >project > rename.

Comment: I just updated the instructions for xcode 4.1, I'm pretty sure 4.2 is the same.  Let me know if it's not.

Comment: weird.. I have updated my question as it seems that this is not the issue I am having now..

Comment: @C.Johns: Did you do a fresh clean of the project?  If not, we may have to still dig into the project settings files (it's been a while since I've had to do this.)

Comment: yea cleaned with no errors. man they have made this a really painfull process aye.

Comment: I'd open up the xcodeproj file with vim and do `:%s/OldProjectName/NewProjectName/gc` and take care to not change things you shouldn't (class files, etc.).  And yes, yes they do.

Comment: I will check it out. cheers dude.. for now though I think I should do some more reading on this. thanks for the help.