# XCode 4.2 - dropdown doesn't change after project rename

Tags: drop-down-menu, xcode4.2, project, device, rename

This question was marked as duplicate, and after the asker succeeded in renaming the project he got the same bug as me, and edited the question:

[How to rename xcode project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959557/how-to-rename-xcode-project-file)

So if you look at the picture you see the device drop-down showing the wrong name. It's still showing the old project name, instead of the renamed one. I have the same issue.

I've searched in the target/project settings - there's no setting containing the old name.

I've done a clean build.

Tried to look for a .build folder to delete, but it's been moved to somewhere else.

Either way, I've run out of things to try, so if you've had this and solved it, just point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, duh. It was schemes. It used the old project's scheme for some reason. Product > New Scheme, click OK, make sure it's the selected one in Product > Edit Scheme.